# grabbing just first link under article tag in python web scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape just the first link under the article tag. So far I have this

```
for link in soup.find("section", {"id": "grid"}).findAll("a", href=re.compile("/recipe/[0-9]*/.*/")):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

which grabs both links under the article tag

http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/250x250/00/17/17/171761.jpg'">

```
<a href="/recipe/17066/janets-rich-banana-bread/" data-internal-referrer-link='hub recipe' data-click-id='cardslot 2' >

    <img class="grid-col__rec-image" data-lazy-load data-original-src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/250x250/00/17/17/171761.jpg" alt="Janet's Rich Banana Bread Recipe and Video - Sour cream guarantees a moist and tender loaf.  And bananas are sliced instead of mashed in this recipe, giving a concentrated banana taste in every bite." title="Janet's Rich Banana Bread Recipe and Video"  src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/ar/spacer.gif" style="display: inline;" />

    <h3 class="grid-col__h3 grid-col__h3--recipe-grid">
        Janet's Rich Banana Bread
            <div class="grid-col__video">
                <a href="/video/1027/janets-rich-banana-bread/" data-internal-referrer-link='hub recipe' data-click-id='cardslot 2'><span class="icon--videoplay-small-white"></span></a>
            </div>
    </h3>
</a>
<a href="/recipe/17066/janets-rich-banana-bread/" data-internal-referrer-link='hub recipe' data-click-id='cardslot 2'>
    <div class="grid-col__ratings">
        <div class="rating-stars" data-scroll-to-anchor="reviews" data-ratingstars= 4.82000017166138 >
    <img height="16" width="16" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/ar-images/icons/rating-stars/full-star-2015.svg"  />
    <img height="16" width="16" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/ar-images/icons/rating-stars/full-star-2015.svg"  />
    <img height="16" width="16" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/ar-images/icons/rating-stars/full-star-2015.svg"  />
    <img height="16" width="16" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/ar-images/icons/rating-stars/full-star-2015.svg"  />
    <img height="16" width="16" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/ar-images/icons/rating-stars/full-star-2015.svg"  />
```

```
        <div class="rec-card__description">Sour cream guarantees a moist and tender loaf.  And bananas are sliced instead of mashed in this recipe, giving a concentrated banana taste in every bite.</div>

    </div>
</a>
<div class="profile profile--recipe-card">
            <a href="/cook/8133/" data-internal-referrer-link='hub recipe' data-click-id='cardslot 2'>
                <ul class="cook-details">
                    <li>
                        <img class="img-profile elevate-cook-thumbnail" alt="profile image" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/mobile/allrecipes/images/icon-user-default_v2.png"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                                <h4><span>Recipe by</span> vjonsson</h4>
                        <ul class="cook-details__followers followers-count">
                            <li>
                                <span class="icon--cook-card-follower" title="Followers"></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><format-large-number number="21"></format-large-number></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="cook-details__favorites favorites-count">
                            <li>
                                <span class="icon--cook-card-favorite" title="Favorites"></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><format-large-number number="0"></format-large-number></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="cook-details__recipes-made recipes-made-count">
                            <li>
                                <span class="icon--cook-card-made" title="Recipes Made"></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span><format-large-number number="3"></format-large-number></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </a>
</div>
```

as you can see there are two links in there and I am trying to get only the first one. any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

'find' function always return one element, whereas 'findAll' return all the elements(in this case all links).
Or you can use limit argument inside findAll:

```
first_link=soup.findAll("a", limit=1)
```

or

```
first_link=soup.find("a")
```

Reference:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Searching%20the%20Parse%20Tree